# Ошибки при инсталляции некоторых модулей через npm

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm

Изучаю Angular, попытался собрать эти проекты:

https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat (стандартный с оф сайта)
и https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp

Проблема в том, что npm не может зарезолвить установку всех node js пакетов (основные - bower, grunt-cli ставятся корректно, но хочется чтобы работало все)

Система: Windows 8.1 64 bit

Пытался гуглить, искал разные решения, ничего не помогло.

Ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смутно помню эту проблему на винде. Насколько я помню, мне удалось ее решить установив нужную версию python. Но не уверен. Node-gyp плохо работает под виндой и есть много материалов в инете, как это исправить. Попробуйте копать в эту сторону.

Comment: C python были проблемы, ему нужна была версия 2.7 в classpath. Это уже после решения проблемы с пайтоном. Буду смотреть что с Node-gyp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это ошибка компиляции для платформы windows. Нужно добавить необходимые инструменты в вашу Windows. Вот пример решения для node-gyp / bcrypt
[Error compiling bcrypt - node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573488/error-compiling-bcrypt-node-js/17934330#17934330). После компиляции node-gyp все будет работать.